# accessing Contacts from Addressbook of Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

Iam working on a application in Which i need contacts which are Stored i iphones AddressBook , is there any sdk or frameWork to access the iphones addressbook ?

Comment: look at the [`AddressBook`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/) and [`AddressBookUI`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007082) frameworks. This is the [`guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744).

Comment: Where have you searched for information on that so far?

Comment: @Eiko Thanks for Comment i had find out what i want now i can access all the contact information from address book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) for this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [Adress Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) from Apple should help you here: